# Get the value from radiobuttonlist through javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a radibutton list.

```
          <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
              RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="flow" >
             <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text ="Yes" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem  Text ="No" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
          </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And to get the value from radio list I have a function :

```
 function getvalueofradiolist() {

        var radiolist = document.getElementById('<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>');
        var rblName = radiolist.name;
        var radio = document.getElementsByName(rblName);

        for (var x = 0; x < radio.length; x++) {
            if (radio[x].checked) {
                alert("Selected item Value " + radio[x].value);
            }
        }
    }
```

But it returns undefined.

Did I write something wrong?

I am calling this function on button click.

Suggest me If I can do this with the help of code behind in spite of Javascript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
          RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="flow" >
         <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text ="Yes" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem  Text ="No" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:RadioButtonList>    </form>
<p id="button" onclick="getvalue()">click me</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getvalue(){
 alert($('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val());
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

regarding the code

```
var rblName = radiolist.name;
```

you don't even have name attribute

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
function getvalueofradiolist() {

            var radioButtonlist = document.getElementsByName("<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%>");
            for (var x = 0; x < radioButtonlist.length; x++) {
                if (radioButtonlist[x].checked) {
                    alert("Selected item Value "  + radioButtonlist[x].value);
                }
}
```

Comment: Suggest me If I can do this with the help of code behind inspite of javascript

Comment: Try changing <%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%> to RadioButtonList1 only.

Answer (score 0):

An dwhat about getting the `input` elements inside directly :

```
function getvalueofradiolist() {
    var radiolist = document.getElementById('<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>');
    var radio = radiolist.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var x = 0; x < radio.length; x++) {
        if (radio[x].type === "radio" && radio[x].checked) {
            alert("Selected item Value " + radio[x].value);
        }
    }
}
```